# Unsure as to why I am receiving an "invalid identifier" error

Tags: sql, oracle, join

After joining three tables, I am unable to call the column "shipping_id" from the "shipment" table.

I've tried re-ordering my joins and other ways of calling the column

```
SELECT shipment.shipping_id (date_of_delivery-order_date) AS "Length of Delivery", 
       damaged, inventory.product_id, name_of_product, price
  FROM shipment
  JOIN orders 
    ON orders.shipping_id = shipment.shipping_id
  JOIN inventory
    ON inventory.product_id = orders.product_id
```

If i remove the first SELECT entry "shipment.shipping_id", the query runs fine.  I am receiving this error...

```
ORA-00904: "SHIPMENT"."SHIPPING_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 8
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot a comma after `shipment.shipping_id`. That makes Oracle think `(date_of_delivery-order_date) AS "Length of Delivery"` is an alias for that column and a clearly ill formated one.

Comment: What is this? `SELECT shipment.shipping_id (date_of_delivery-order_date) AS "Length of Delivery"`?  Not even a valid syntax.  Thus the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing comman after shipping_id.  Since you're joining on shipping_id, there is no need to qualify the reference.  There is only a single shipping_id column in the result.

Comment: Doesn't harm to qualify either. Besides, if you look at the first `ON` clause, `orders` has a `shipping_id` too.

Comment: Agreed. Just noting it's not required.

Comment: But it is. Again look at `ON orders.shipping_id = shipment.shipping_id`. `orders` has a column of that name too. And even if it wasn't required, that note would better fit in a comment than an answer.